# Should a teaching statement be posted publicly on the web?

Tags: website, teaching-statement

I noticed that some professors and instructors have their teaching statement available on their webpages, and others don't.

I thought teaching statements were used mainly for applying for jobs, so since these professors and instructors have jobs, what is the purpose of having their teaching statement available to the public?

**Is there an advantage to posting the teaching statement publicly?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be advantageous to post your application materials publicly while you are searching for a job (because it alerts a broader audience to your job search and lets them quickly find out more).  Once your search is over, I see no career advantage to keeping these materials on the web.  I think the main reason to do so is as a service to others.  It's useful for graduate students to see a wide range of research and teaching statements, so that they have a clearer idea of what they typically look like.  This if possible only if some people make theirs available.

There are also several other reasons someone's teaching statement may remain available.  One is that they forgot to take it down, and another is that they feel it provides students with useful information about their approach to teaching.  However, I'd bet that keeping it online as a public service is the most common reason.

Comment: People post just about anything on the web to show what they're doing and what they've done. It might just be that. I prefer said statements over selfies anytime...

Answer (score 2):

I think posting a teaching statement that details your own pedagogical goals and insights as well as your teaching experience is an excellent way to:

1. help students and colleagues get to know you.
2. challenge yourself to improve and work towards your teaching goals.
3. challenge yourself to reflect on your teaching.
4. get feedback on your approaches to teaching and relating to students.

In short, I think there are plenty of real advantages in clearly expressing your teaching philosophy and sharing your views with others that aren't directly related to securing a position or "getting ahead" in terms of career advancement.

Everyone can be cynical once in awhile, especially when they're being put through the wringer by the frustrating and very competitive application process.
However, most people working in academia take pride in their work and a teaching statement is generally a lot more than a bit of puffery for a job application.
In my own experience as an undergraduate student, many of the best instructors I encountered in my coursework had public teaching statements and were very open about how and why they did things in their classes.